# desinstalar projetos do ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic, apache-cordova

criei vários projetos para teste no Ionic, mas agora necessito exclui-lo. Já pesquisei muito sobe isso, mas não encontrei nenhuma solução. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um comando para isto, você deve fazer na mão:

**Windows**: `rmdir "nome da pasta"`

**Linux**: `rm -rf nomedapasta`